# Login to windows authenticated domain when not connected to domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.NET Windows Authenticated application.  When I am in my office, I can connect to this application without any issues, as I am logged into the domain and connect through my local server such as:  SERVER\APPLICATION

But, if I am out on the road and I need to connect to that application I would use:

http://someserver.com/application

When I connect, it wants me to Authenticate and I need to supply my domain login and password.  This works great as well.

What I want to do, is setup my browser to authenticate for me.  I thought that in the past you could send your login and password as part of the URL so it would authenticate you, but I might be mistaken... Could have been a netscape thing... :)

Is this possible, so I don't have to login each time?

Answer (score 2):

Passing credentials in the URL is usually not a good idea. They are visible to anything in between & recorded in the web server logs. I seem to remember IE disabled this, as it was used for spoofing URLs.

Windows Auth is not really designed for use through firewalls. Negotiate is the preferred method, but this requires a kerberos token from an AD server, which you won't have if you're not in the office. Your browser then defaults to NTLM, which is a challenge-response protocol that will work through firewalls, but is less secure. IE should use your credentials, but depending on how you signed it, you may find you need to enter your credentials.

Answer (score -1):

**Control Panel** --> **User Accounts**  -->  **Manage your credentials** (on left panel)

Take a look at this [MSFT article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Manage-stored-passwords-certificates-and-other-credentials) for a little bit more detail

Comment: To the downvoters, would like to know what is not correct about the answer. The op asked for a way to pass credentials automatically without user intervention, and this method provides that functionality.